# How to resolve NoReverseMatch in django while using reverse with id as argument?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I've been getting the NoReverseMatch presumably from having passing id value greater than 9.

So here's the error message I'm getting :

```
Reverse for 'article-details' with arguments '('2', '9')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['a/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

here's my code:

Models.py

```
class Post( models.Model):
title = models.CharField( max_length = 250 )
author = models.ForeignKey( User , on_delete=models.CASCADE )
body = models.TextField()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    print((self.id))
    return reverse('article-details' , args= str(self.id))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path ( 'a/<int:pk>' ,  ArticleDetailView.as_view() , name='article-details' ) ,
path('create/' , CreatePost2.as_view() , name='create_post' ) ,
path ( 'p/<int:pk>' ,  postDetails , name= 'post-details' ) ,
```

]

I think that since i have upward of 10 entries in database whenever reverse is called with id > 9 it interprets it as touple with 2 values.

How do i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Args takes an iterable like a tuple. But a string is also an iterable, so if you pass a single string `'29'`, it will interpret this as *two* parameters `2` and `9`.

You should wrap the `self.id` (or perhaps better `self.pk`), in a singleton tuple:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article-details' , args=(self.pk,))
```